# Can a differential equation be both homogeneous differential equation and separable differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

[This](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/first-order-differential-equations/homogeneous-equations/v/first-order-homegenous-equations) tutorial of `Khan Academy` suggests that if `dy/dx = f(x,y)` can be written as `dy/dx = F(y/x)` then it's homogeneous differential equation.

Consider following example as `dy/dx = x^2/y` is separable but it also has been written in the form of `y/x` so is it separable and homogeneous both?
[image]

Comment: $y' = y/x$ is homogeneous and separable. But there is one trouble: $y' = x^2/y$ is not homogeneous.

Comment: `But there is one trouble: y′=x2/y is not homogeneous.` How? Can you please explain using the same method as used by `Khan Academy` @MichaelGaluza

Comment: Do you mean to say that x/y/x would be simplified as x^2/y ? @MichaelGaluza

Comment: Just check definitions. If you multiply $x$ and $y$ by $t$, $dy/dx$ doesn't change, but $(tx)^2/(ty) = t\cdot x^2/y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 
$$
\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac{x}{(y/x)}
$$
Then $\frac {dy}{dx}$ is a function of **both** $x$ and $y/x$.  Since it not a function of *only* $y/x$, the differential equation you describe is not homogeneous.

As indicated by the comments, however, there are differential equations that are both separable and homogeneous.